# Add line break to one line of a multi-line equation

Tags: equations, line-breaking, align

I am writing an equation consisting of many lines, however, one particular line is very long and I want to break into a new line.

For example:

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &   \text{minimise}     &&  COST = A + B \\
    &   \text{subject to}   &&  A = A_1 + A_2 \\
    &                       &&  B = B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4 + B_5 + B_6 + B_7 \\ % this line is too long
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Based on above example, I want to add a line break into the last line.

Comment: Aligned can be nested. Just use another one, might be an idea to add `[t] ` to it.

Answer (score 3):

If it is just breaking, you can use `multlined` from `mathtools` (which is an extended form of `amsmath`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &   \text{minimise}     &&  COST = A + B \\
    &   \text{subject to}   &&  A = A_1 + A_2 \\
    &                       &&  B = \!\begin{multlined}[t]
                                        B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4 + B_5 \\
                                           + B_6 + B_7  % this line is too long
                                    \end{multlined}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick suggestion (also using the `align` environment):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section*{Original (\texttt{aligned})}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &   \text{minimise}     &&  \text{COST} = A + B \\
    &   \text{subject to}   &&  A = A_1 + A_2 \\
    &                       &&  B = B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4 + B_5 + B_6 + B_7 \\ % this line is too long
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\section*{\texttt{aligned} modified}

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &   \text{minimise}     &&  \text{COST} = A + B \\
    &   \text{subject to}   &&  A = A_1 + A_2 \\
    &                       &&  B = B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4 + \\ & &&  + B_5 + B_6 + B_7 % this line is too long
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\section*{\texttt{align}}

\begin{align}
    &   \text{minimise}    &   \text{COST} &= A + B \\
    &   \text{subject to}   &  A &= A_1 + A_2 \\
    &                      &   B &= B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4  +\\ & & & + B_5 + B_6 + B_7 % this line is too long
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Leading to:

[image]

### Remark

To avoid the addidtional equation number (6) you can use the `amsmath` command `\nonumber`, see also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230394).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    &   \text{minimise}     &  COST &= A + B \\
    &   \text{subject to}   &  A &= A_1 + A_2 \\
    &                       &  B &= 
    \! % feature
    \begin{aligned}[t]
        &B_1 + B_2 + B_3 + B_4 + B_5 + B_6 + B_7
        \\
        &+\dots+B_n 
        \end{aligned}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose this, built with `alignedat`, and a smaller vertical spacing between the two parts of the broken line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier, heuristica}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\AMod}[1]{\prescript{#1}{}{\text{Mod}}}

\newcommand{\BMod}[1]{{}^{#1}\text{Mod}}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    & \text{minimise} & \text{COST}& = A + B \\
    & \text{subject to:} & \smash{\rule[-1.9\baselineskip]{0.6pt}{2.4\baselineskip}\ } A &= A_1 + A_2 \\
    & & B& = B_1\begin{aligned}[t] & + B_2 + B_3+ B_4 \\[-0.5ex] & + B_5 + B_6 + B_7\end{aligned}
    \end{alignedat}
  \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]