# Why 'split' environment conflicts with my counter?

Tags: mathtools, split

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{rule}
\newcommand\jrule{
  \refstepcounter{rule}
  \label{foo}
  \text{R\ref{foo}}}
\section{Intro}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
& \jrule \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

It prints `R1.1` instead of `R1`.

However, if I don't use `split` environment, it prints `R1`. What is the problem?

Comment: You can put `\label` outside of `split`, right after the `\begin{equation}`.

Comment: Is it possible to keep `\refstepcounter{rule}\label{foo}` inside `split` and still render the right output?

Comment: I think you should change `equation*` to `equation`.

Comment: Is it possible to use `equation*` and then use `\refstepcounter{rule}\label{foo}` inside `split`? :)

Comment: I am confused: what are you trying to achieve? It seems like you want to use unnumbered environment, while making it behave as if it's numbered.

Comment: I want to refer to my own counter, which has nothing to do with `equation`

Comment: as amsmath processes environments twice and has its own numbering logic it handles \label in a quite special way. You get for example errors if there are two \label in the equation and in your case the reference is wrong because of the grouping. Do you really need a label-ref system? In your example you could simply use `\therule`.

Comment: But you could try this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230396/2388

Comment: Why is this tagged mathtools when it is not related to mathtools (it is related to amsmath which is automatically loaded my mathtools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{rule}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\jrule{%
  \refstepcounter{rule}%
  \ltx@label{R@\roman{rule}}%
  (\mathrm{R}\ref{R@\roman{rule}})%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x&=y \\
&=\jrule
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note that I didn't use a fixed label that would not work.

[image]

If you want to be able to refer to the number, you can add an optional argument to `\jrule`; you *cannot* use `\label` in this context, because `amsmath` redefines it in its various math display environments in order to get correct references.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcounter{rule}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\jrule{o}{%
  \refstepcounter{rule}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% no optional argument, use a generated label
    \ltx@label{R@\roman{rule}}%
    (\mathrm{R}\ref{R@\roman{rule}})%
  }{% optional argument, use it for the label
    \ltx@label{#1}%
    (\mathrm{R}\ref{#1})%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
x&=y \\
&=\jrule \\
&=\jrule[foo]
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\ref{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, it's important for me to have the ability to use `\ref{foo}` later on. Can you please alter your code to enable this?

Comment: @yegor256 See edit.