# my 'newcounter' depends on package '\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}', how to fix that?

Tags: amsmath, tex-core

The problem is in counter 'jrule' as in:
[Why 'split' conflicts with my counter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663514/why-split-conflicts-with-my-counter)

I have this document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{rule}
\newcommand\rrule[1]{{\bfseries\sffamily R\ref{rule:#1}}}
\makeatletter\newcommand\jrule[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{rule}%
  \ltx@label{rule:#1}%
  \text{\rrule{#1}}}\makeatother%
\section{Intro}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{x + y}{z - f}\jrule{1}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Here, `\jrule` works stange:
[image]

But if I remove `\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}`, it works well:
[image]

How can I solve this problem, without deleting "cleveref" package?

Comment: why use label here at all, you could simply print the number

Comment: @yegor256 So, welcome to your colleague!

Answer (score 2):

The `cleveref` package redefines the standard `label` command to have an optional argument. Only later `amsmath` does `\let\ltx@label=\label`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\newcounter{rule}
\crefname{rule}{rule}{rules}
\Crefname{rule}{Rule}{Rules}

\newcommand\rrule[1]{{\bfseries\sffamily R\ref{rule:#1}}}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\jrule[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{rule}%
  \ltx@label[rule]{rule:#1}%
  \textnormal{\rrule{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\subsection{Overview}

\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{x + y}{z - f}\jrule{1}
\end{equation*}

See~\cref{rule:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid defining commands after `\begin{document}`.